# Create child process with custom environment using boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-process

The documentation [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/process.html) doesn't provide any example for creating a child process with a custom environment using `process::child(...)`.
An example is given with `process::system(...)` but the function `system` has less possible operations (such as pipes or waitpid) so I would like to have a full example using `process::child` if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in system.hpp, system_impl, which supports custom env, is implemented in terms of child,

```
template<typename IoService, typename ...Args>
inline int system_impl(
        std::true_type, /*needs ios*/
        std::true_type, /*has io_context*/
        Args && ...args)
{
    IoService & ios = ::boost::process::detail::get_io_context_var(args...);

    system_impl_success_check check;

    std::atomic_bool exited{false};

    child c(std::forward<Args>(args)...,
            check,
            ::boost::process::on_exit(
                [&](int, const std::error_code&)
                {
                    ios.post([&]{exited.store(true);});
                }));
    if (!c.valid() || !check.succeeded)
        return -1;

    while (!exited.load())
        ios.poll();

    return c.exit_code();
}
```

So the call to system from the docs:

```
bp::system("stuff", bp::env["VALUE_1"]="foo", bp::env["VALUE_2"]+={"bar1", "bar2"});
```

which calls:

```
template<typename ...Args>
inline int system(Args && ...args)
{
    typedef typename ::boost::process::detail::needs_io_context<Args...>::type
            need_ios;
    typedef typename ::boost::process::detail::has_io_context<Args...>::type
            has_ios;
    return ::boost::process::detail::system_impl<boost::asio::io_context>(
            need_ios(), has_ios(),
            std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

translates into this function, so you should be able to do the same.

Comment: apparently args are sent to `child` but it does not compile with child

Answer (score 4):

The last answer and comment are quite old but I can confirm that `boost::process::child` with environment parameter works using Boost version 1.65 under Ubuntu 18.04. The documentation about that is quite thin, so I had to find out by myself:

```
std::string command = "/usr/bin/something";
ipstream pipe_stream;

// Get current env
auto env = boost::this_process::environment();
// Add something
env["CHINESE_FOOD"] = "GOOD";
// Change something
env["CHINESE_FOOD"] = "GREAT";
// Delete something
env["CHINESE_FOOD"].clear();

boost::process::child childProc(command, env, std_out > pipe_stream);
```

And of course, if environment is not needed, it will inherit from parent process automatically

```
std::string command = "/usr/bin/something";
ipstream pipe_stream;

boost::process::child childProc(command, std_out > pipe_stream);
```

Comment: For some reason on Linux (CentOS 7) passing a boost::this_process::environment object to boost::process::child constructor also changes the environment of the parent process. Is this intended?

Comment: You are right, according to Boost documentation my last exemple will modify the current process environment.  The correct way here would have been:
`
// Get current env
auto env = boost::this_process::environment();
// Copy it into an environment separate to the one of this process
boost::process::environment envChild = env;
// Add something
envChild["CHINESE_FOOD"] = "GOOD";
// Change something
envChild["CHINESE_FOOD"] = "GREAT";
// Delete something
envChild["CHINESE_FOOD"].clear();

boost::process::child childProc(command, envChild, std_out > pipe_stream);`

Comment: You can also declare an empty environment instead of taking the one from the process `boost::process::environment env;`

Comment: ahh... Yes! My mistake was that I had wrong assumption about `boost::process::native_environment` type. I had to copy it to `boost::process::environment` and further modify it. `boost::process::native_environment` is a copyable accessor object!